# How to make right routes config for local files

Tags: angular

I have added local files to `assets/doc/doc.pdf` to get them under `localhost:4200/assets/doc/doc.pdf`
Here is my **route configs**

```
const notFound = {
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent
};
const mainRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainPageComponent,
      },
      ...allMenu,
      // ...authentication,
      { ...siteMap },
      { ...goLogin },
      { ...notFound },
    ]
  },
];
```

When I try to get my documents I am always redirected to `PgeNotFoundComponenet` and on second reload of page I can see my document. What is going wrong ? How should I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDF is considered as **assets** , directly serving from the web server. Think like its a JS or CSS or any image file, that is directly getting served from Web Server not from Angular. And How browser load these files is different than the Angular routing works.

Angular routing works only for the application routing strategy. So while you navigating to pdf file with route it go to 404 , you should use a tag with absolute path from assets and then navigate.

```
<a href="www.google.com/assets/doc/doc.pdf">Get PDF</a>
```

Something like that then it will load the pdf in the browser, that was happening when you reload the page, because the path might getting updated in the browser.